# ng-change in select not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update a list2 from a list1, and i used ng-change for that.

My app is fully configured and the controller for the html page is well setted.

The only thing that when i select the elemt from my first list1 the method updateList2 never invocked

```
<label>NameLIst1</label>
<select ng-model="idLIST1" 
        ng-change="updateList2(idLIST1)"
        ng-options="elt.id as elt.name for elt in list1">

        <option  value="">select one</option>
</select>

<label>Name LIST 2</label>
<select  ng-model="idLIST2"                 
        ng-options="elt.id as id.name for elt in list2">

        <option  value="">select one</option>
</select>


$scope.updateList2 = function(id){
alert("id ="+id);
}
```

Comment: Errors in your console?  Does the app work at all?

Comment: Please upload a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co)...

Comment: You don't need to pass a param to `updateList2` function. `$scope.updateList2 = function() { alert($scope.idLIST1) }`

Comment: yes it works the app, only for the ng-change, i tried also with no param and no invocation

Comment: it doesn't enter even in the function when debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have code which are written in below ,try this 
it's work fine,also work with param,
but you don't need to pass param in methods

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="TestController">
    <label>NameLIst1</label>
    <select ng-model="idLIST1"
            ng-change="updateList2(idLIST1)"
            ng-options="elt.id as elt.name for elt in list1">

        <option value="">select one</option>
    </select>

    <label>Name LIST 2</label>
    <select ng-model="idLIST2"
            ng-options="elt.id as id.name for elt in list2">

        <option value="">select one</option>
    </select>
</div>

var app = angular.module("test", ["ngRoute"])
        .controller("TestController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list1 = [
               { id: 1, name: 'data1' },
               { id: 2, name: 'data2' },
               { id: 3, name: 'data3' },
               { id: 4, name: 'data4' },
            ];
            $scope.updateList2 = function (id) {
                alert("id =" + id);
            }
        }
        ]);
```